# Workflow to clean badly scanned sheet music

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I am looking for a workflow that would clean (and possibly straighten) old and badly scanned images of musical scores (like the one below).

I've tried to use denoise, hough filters, imagemagick geometry filters, and I am struggling to identify the series of filters that remove the scanner noise/bias.

[image]

Comment: The image you have there is quite, QUITE, bad. The solution won't likely be easy nor scalable to other samples of your data set. Be prepared to lose a lot of the original signal (or image). I wouldn't be surprised if Deep Learning is the sole viable option here for this kind of reconstruction.

Comment: @stateMachine That could be a good idea. Do you have hints on how could I artificially generate a similar noise pattern so that I can train a NN for the role?

Comment: I would go further and claim that this needs manual user input. at best you can hope to clean it up a little and help the user transcribe the notes accurately.

Comment: I think I might have read something about this in [this book](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17O2IOx9gbUB4L1c3pdU6RSN4x8eplewx/view?usp=sharing) but I can't remember

Answer (score 0):

Just some quick ideas:

1. Remove grayscale noise: Do a low pass filter (darks), since the music is darker than a lot of the noise. Remaining noise is mostly vertical lines.
2. Rotate image: Sum grayscale values for each column of the image. You'll get a vector with the total pixel lightness in that column. Use gradient descent or search on the rotation of the image (within some bounds like +/-15deg rotation) to maximize the variance of that vector. Idea here is that the vertical noise lines indicate vertical alignment, and so we want the columns of the image to align with these noise lines (= maximized variance).
3. Remove vertical line noise: After rotation, take median value of each column. The greater the distance (squared difference) a pixel is from that median darkness, the more confident we are it is its true color (e.g. a pure white or black pixel when vertical noise was gray). Since noise is non-white, you could try blending this distance by the whiteness of the median for an alternative confidence metric. Ideally, I think here you'd train some 7x7x2 convolution filter (2 channels being pixel value and distance from median) to estimate true value of the pixel. That would be the most minimal machine learning approach, not using some full-fledged NN. However, given your lack of training data, we'll have to come up with our own heuristic for what the true pixel value is. You likely will need to play around with it, but here's what I think might work:

   - Set some threshold of confidence; above that threshold we take the value as is. Below the threshold, set to white (the binary expected pixel value for the entire page).
   - For all values below threshold, take the max confidence value within a +/-2 pixels L1 distance (e.g. 5x5 convolution) as that pixel's value. Seems like features are separated by at least 2 pixels, but for lower resolutions that window size may need to be adjusted. Since white pixels may end up being more confident overall, you could experiment with prioritizing darker pixels (increase their confidence somehow).
   - Clamp the image contrast and maybe run another low pass filter.

Comment: Playing around I notice the vertical lines seem to curve slightly at the top, so you could try computing this in chunks of say 100px vertical. Or instead of having the aggregated column sums/medians be over the whole image, do the aggregation in 100px windows.

Comment: Many thanks for the insights. I will try to code something around those lines and share the results!